# Automatically grant "control access -> enter" to low rep users on "convert to chat"

Tags: feature-request, chat

Regarding the question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111942/allow-inviting-people-with-rep-20-to-private-chat) low-rep users (such as the OP user especially) should automatically be granted the needed permissions to view the converted chat.  Without this functionality, users will not be able to converse within their own conversation.

It seemed like a different question (if not linked) than he was asking, so I made a new question for it.

Answer (score 3):

> Without this functionality, users will not be able to converse within their own conversation.

This is based on wrong assumptions. Moving comment discussions doesn't work if one of the users doesn't have the reputation to chat.

Comment: As mentioned in this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111942/allow-inviting-people-with-rep-20-to-private-chat  Something happened where it was.. soo....