# Can we allow users with 1k reputation (or something) to grant users without the reputation access to a specific chat room?

Tags: feature-request, chat, privileges

There have been several times I have been helping a user with a question and things aren't quite working out perfectly, and the comments keep getting longer and longer and longer. We've all been there, the comment system isn't made for long discussions, and at some point we just want to throw up our hands and give up.

I've tried creating a chat room to discuss the issue in a better environment, but if they have less than 20 reputation that isn't possible. If you are room owner of that chat room (like you probably are if you created it) and have 1k rep you can make a room read-only, but you can't give a user explicit write access to a room, even though you have access to the controls.

[image]

## TL;DR

Can we please allow users with 1k (or some amount) of reputation the ability to give write access to users with less than 20 reputation in chat? [Currently only moderators can do this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111942/allow-inviting-people-with-rep-20-to-private-chat/111946#comment290591_111946).

<sup>This question [Allow temporary guest accounts in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82738/allow-temporary-guest-accounts-in-chat) is related, but isn't really the same request.</sup>

Comment: @psubsee2003 Ah, thanks for pointing that out. Surprised I didn't find it.