# Please use chat room - only you can't

Tags: support, comments, chat

I am new to Stack Overflow. After commenting repeatedly on an answer from somebody, suddenly a warning (automatic, I guess) popped up: "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?"

I get the idea behind this move. Only problem: As a newbie, I can't use chat rooms. Wouldn't it be better to show this warning only, if you actually can use chat rooms?

On a side note: These automatic warning messages might scare away new users. My first posting got a warning like "Postings with these headlines are often down voted and deleted". It nearly made me leave the site. Maybe a less restrictive warning, if you are not a repeat offender, would increase the attractiveness to new members.

Comment: there are a couple of feature requests to open chat for < 20 rep: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111942/allow-inviting-people-with-rep-20-to-private-chat?rq=1

Comment: *It nearly made me leave the site* Well, a lot of new users don't care at all about all the guidance and warnings we throw at them so if some are scared away by that I would say they served their goal. The community here doesn't want to cater for everyone, only for the few that care about putting effort and quality in their posts. If you notice and then try to figure out how to improve the wording of the post you should be fine.

Comment: @rene I get the whole idea of warnings. Problem was that my headline sounded similar to other problems, only it was different - not that a machine algorithm would know the difference, because the same keywords were used. Thanks for pointing me to the relevant thread - fully support, what Lukas Knuth says about inviting newbies into chats.